# Emgucv drawn items

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am making a project using `Emgucv` library, he problem is as follows,

1. I Capture image
2. detect feature
3. extract it
4. draw it

After that i copy the drawn items in a blank image, now I want find contours inside that new image, but the result is always bull, Why is That?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Additional information would be good.

But for you to be able to find the contours, the new image must be converted into a binary image like the ff: (assuming newImage is of type Image)

```
Image<Gray,byte> binaryImage = newImage.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(1), new Gray(255));
```

To detect contours and write to resultImage:

```
for (var contour = binaryImage.FindContours(
        CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, 
        RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_CCOMP); 
        contour != null; 
        contour = contour.HNext)
    {
        resultImage.Draw(contour, new Gray(255), -1);
    }
```